# iOS Swift Framework with Static library, getting linker command failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I am creating an iOS dynamic framework with a third party library, MiSnap, being accessed through it (used for scan checks, driving license  & other documents).

I have a file and some header files provided by MiSnap.

When i try to build the framework I get the following linker error. Seems like it couldn't find the constants even though these constants are defined in the header file provided.

[image: Errors]

These constants are defined like this in the Header file provided.

```
extern NSString* const kMiSnapCaptureMode;
```

Comment: What is the file you have in addition to the headers?  Is it a static library with a `.a` extension?  Did you add it as a library to link with, via linker flags, and in the library search path?  Did you add the headers to the header search path?  You can set these in Build Settings.

Comment: @OmniProg thanks your answer worked. I added .a file to framework.